# JBoss Startup Notification

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, startup

I want to log some information (builddate, svn revision, ...), after my `ear` package was successfully deployed.
I have searched a round a abit and I came over autostarting Servlets and JMX Notification Listeners. All a little bit overkill for 3 lines of log ;)

For clearification: I'm searching a way to call a method after sucessful deploy and EJB startup (also after hotdeploy)

So is there a way to do this? Some jboss-*.xml hack?

greetings Florian

Comment: Quite obviously, you will need an application specific solution. JBoss does not care what your EAR was built with or what SCM you are using (if you are even using one). What version of JEE are you on?

Comment: Yeah, that's clear that i must provide the output. I'm looking for a way to call a Method/Class after successful EAR deployment. I'm on jboss 5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved the problem this way:

I created a JBoss ManagedBean (JMX) wich has an @EJB Injection to the EJB which gets loaded at least.

Then i added some output to the start() Method.

greetings Florian

Answer (score 0):

You can display the version information in some UI page or a log (during app initialization with some static code in class, servlet etc) by reading it from a resource file.

And during the build process you should write version number in the resource file.

Comment: i already have the information about the build number/time available. I need a way to call a method after sucessful EAR Deployment

Answer (score 0):

Are there any Servlets in your EAR?  If yes, you could implement [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) and override contextInitialized method to print information you need in logs.